# Get Windows Process/File Description in Python

Tags: python, windows

I have the following code so far that tells me every time a new process is created.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while True:
    new_process = process_watcher()
    print(new_process.Caption)
    print(new_process.ExecutablePath)
```

This works fine, but what I'm really trying to do is get at the Processes Description because while the filename of what I'm looking for might change, the description does not. I can't find anything in Win32_Process or win32file that gets me the file description though. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you say there is no `Description` attribute of `new_process`? According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx there should be.

Comment: err, allow me to reword. There is a Description attribute, however it doesn't actually give you the description. It gives you the same '*.exe' that name or caption would give you.

Comment: Did you look at the zillions of other properties?

Comment: yeah...i tried a bunch that I thought it might be, but none came up with the description.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
try:
    new_process = process_watcher()

    proc_owner = new_process.GetOwner()
    proc_owner = "%s\\%s" % (proc_owner[0],proc_owner[2])
    create_date = new_process.CreationDate
    executable = new_process.ExecutablePath
    cmdline = new_process.CommandLine
    pid = new_process.ProcessId
    parent_pid = new_process.parentProcessId
    privileges = "N/A"
    process_log_message = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\r\n" % (create_date,proc_owner,executable,cmdline,pid,parent_pid,privileges)
    print "1"
    print process_log_message
    log_to_file(process_log_message)
except:
    print "2"
    pass
```

Hope this helps :)